# What is the best way to handle variable JSON data in Symfony using twig?

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, twig

For a project I need to show on a website the JSON result of a particular PHP call. For this, a Symfony project including a corresponding `html.twig` page is already setup.

Automatically I wanted to start converting the JSON object into PHP objects sothat I can use them for the implementation of the output form. What I did not think about and ran into was that in the render function, which is used to copy PHP variables to the `html.twig` page sothat they can be used there, cannot handle objects. Only strings and string arrays. (correct me if I am wrong)

After this, I wanted to do the same in Javascript, but Twig does not work with Javascript...

What is a nice and clean way to convert variable JSON data into an HTML page? I prefer not to use Javascript as confident information is involved in the JSON data.

> MyController.php

```
public function handleJSON(): Response
{
   return $this->render('output.html.twig', [ 'variable1' => 'value', 'variable2' => 'value2' ]);
}
```

> output.html.twig

```
<div> Variable 1 </div>
<p>{{ variable1 }}</p>
<div> Variable 2 </div>
<p>{{ variable2 }}</p>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You want to show the `json` respresentation of a variable in your template? You can use the built-in filter [json_encode](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html). Also twig is perfectly able to adjust/generate javascript, it's javascript that is not able to adjust/modify twig

Comment: That is correct. I have a complex json object which cannot be converted 1 on 1 to html object. Maybe the best thing to do is converting the json object into a new object that can be displayed 1 on 1 to the user with json_encode as you suggest. The complex structure makes it hard as I need to fetch specific data out of it. I have a question answers JSON tree which I need to loop through and depending on which formobject I have, I need to digg deeper. Shortly said, not all information is needed to be displayed.

Comment: You could always implement `jsonSerializable` on your entity so you can decide yourself which information needs to be included in the `json_encode`?

Answer (score 0):

On Symfony you can pass php object on your render. And in twig you can use for exemple the method `getName()` equal in twig `{{ var.name }}`. Twig test if there are the method getName on your php class. If you don't want to use an ascessor but a simple method use its name, Look the doc [template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-variables). So for you controller convert the json to php object and render

```php
public function handleJSON(): Response
{
   return $this->render('output.html.twig', ['phpObject' => $obj]);
}
```

In your twig

```
<div>{{ phpObject.name }}{# for getName #}</div>
<p>{{ phpObject.translation("en"){# for the method translation(string $val) #} }}</p>
```

And you can use js on twig but twig render html code for the client, and you can import js file and css on your twig by the [webpack](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)

I'm sorry for my english

Comment: I did not specify but webpack optimizes the size of files (css, js) sent to the client. It concatenates your css, js files to a single file but you can configure this behavior. There are still many other features ^^

Answer (score 0):

You cold use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT:

```
<pre>{{ article|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}</pre>
```